# Confusion about quantum tunneling through potential energy vs quantum tunneling through energy spectrum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, quantum-tunneling

[image]

It seems like that the drawing above describes the "energy spectrum" of a (final) hamiltonian. However, whenever we talk about quantum tunneling, we describe it as traversing through some kind of potential energy. How does quantum tunneling happen by going from one point of its own energy spectrum to another point, instead of going from one point of potential energy diagram to another point? The "point" is denoted as configuration in the above diagram, which is also mysterious to me.

Ref: [Question about tunneling diagram in adiabatic quantum computation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/317713/)

Comment: Look at this http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/barr.html . It is a quantum mechanical probability distribution versus an x called configuration, possibly because it is a complicated variable in some solid state lattice. Cost is the energy level of the tunneling particle

Comment: @anna v thanks. "Cost is the energy level of the tunneling particle". Does it imply that it has different energy at different position and it is tunneling through its own energy?

Comment: if you look at the link I gave,  you can see that the particle does not change energy, the probability of finding it at a given x changes. The quantum mechanical solution is one function for all of x. The boundary conditions give probabilities for where a particle can be found. With infinite barriers they are completely contained within the region of the potential , otherwise there is a probability of tunneling out at the same energy as the bound energy level.

Comment: As I look at the plot again, it is the barriers at a given energy: compare with the plot in the link . Probably because the barriers model a solid or a real situation.

Comment: I am not up to really answering this because it is in the domain of quantum annealing of which I am no expert. The way I  interpret the wikipedia graph you show above is that it is the result of attempting by a computation to find  the potential function describing a many body system.  The graph shows the consecutive barriers of this potential function ( similar to the hyperphysics plot linked above) as computed by the quantum annealing program.  If the particle had to overcome the barrier it would cost it extra energy,

Comment: Quantum tunneling allows it at the given energy to have a probability of manifesting outside the barrier.